# MongoDB PHP Query Builder UI?

Tags: php, cakephp, mongodb

I'm looking to see if anyone has information on existing code/ references for a MongoDB Query Builder UI.

I've googled without success, I've found a few different examples with MySQL but MongoDB appears to be a bit more elusive.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB is still in the very infant phases of UI tools. The MongoDB website lists a few [admin UI tools](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs). Included in the list are [phpMoAdmin](http://www.phpmoadmin.com/) and [RockMongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo) which are both written in PHP. The [JMongoBrowser](http://edgytech.com/jmongobrowser/) is written by one of the 10gen java driver maintainers and also has several basic browsing / admin features.

However, none of these really have a **"Query Builder"** UI. You're expected to know which fields are in the DB and basically enter queries using the javascript syntax.

This is still a big hole in the MongoDB world, however, it's also a different beast from existing **"Query Builders"**. If you look at the MongoDB query language, you will quickly see some basic problems:

- MongoDB does not have "fixed columns".
- MongoDB has no join syntax.
- The structure of MongoDB documents can vary within a collection.

So you get into lots of problems:

- How do I know which fields can be queried? Am I really going to loop over 5 billion documents to find the available fields?
- How do I query dynamically named sub-objects? Nested sub-objects?
- How do I query Arrays of objects?
- What about arrays of objects that contain more arrays of objects? (*note that MongoDB is poor for this one, regardless of tooling*)
- How do I even name all of these sub-fields?
- How do I display this data? Right now most tools offer both a column view and a JSON view, but there are clearly more option here.

At the end of the day any reasonable "query builder" would need to know something about your schema in advance which definitely causes a lot of issues. If you do find something that handles this, please let me know, would love to see such a tool.